# Python skipping methods

Tags: python, sqlite, debugging, generator

I have the following methods that I am trying to debug.  My problem is that when I call the insertNewDataInDatabase() method from main it goes to the start of the for loop in the method, but skips over the database execution statement and immediately goes to the     getInStockItems() method which doesn't make sense to me because I already called that method and insertNewDataInDatabase doesn't call it.

dataset is a generator object if that has bearing on the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
def deleteOldDataFromDatabase(company, c):
    c.execute('DELETE FROM company WHERE Company=?',(company,))


def insertNewDataInDatabase(items, c):
    for each in items:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ammo VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', ("NULL", each["Company"], each["Value"],
                                                             each["Product"], each["Price"], each["Url"]))
def getInStockItems(c):
    for i in chain(ctd.main()):
        deleteOldDataFromDatabase(i[1], c)
        for each in i[0]:
            yield each

def retrieveDatafromDB(c):
    c.execute("SELECT * from company")
    return c.fetchall()

def main():
    with sqlite3.connect(database) as connection:
        c = connection.cursor()
        dataset = getInStockItems(c)
        insertNewDataInDatabase(dataset, c)
        return retrieveDatafromDB(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm following it in the Pycharm debugger.  It hits the for each line in insertNewDataInDatabase() but instead of going to the execute statement it goes to getInStockItems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *expected behaviour*. `getInStockItems()` is a generator function, and the body of a generator function is not executed until you iterate over the generator.

From the [`yield` expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) documentation:

> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator. That generator then controls the execution of a generator function. The execution starts when one of the generator’s methods is called. At that time, the execution proceeds to the first `yield` expression, where it is suspended again, returning the value of `expression_list` to generator’s caller.

The line `dataset = getInStockItems(c)` creates that generator. You pass the generator to `insertNewDataInDatabase()` and the `for` loop starts iterating over the generator. Iteration means the [`generator.next()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.next) is called, advancing the generator function.

So, until `for each in items:` starts executing, `getInStockItems()` does nothing at all. Calling `.next()` on the generator starts running that function, until the `yield` statement returns the first `i[0]` expression to the `for` loop, at which point it the generator function is suspended again.